# How to disable all log of third party libraries in my Qt5 app?

Tags: logging, qt5, disable

I can disable all log from my app in release mode by set up `qInstallMessageHandler`. But there are still some log from third party libraries that I used. Is there any way to disable all log to console without modify other libraries? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just an idea, but you could stream to a file the `cout` and `cerr` streams.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  std::ofstream file;
  file.open("output.txt");
  std::streambuf *std_buffer = std::cout.rdbuf();
  std::cout.rdbuf(file.rdbuf());

  std::cout << "this is a log" << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```